# VCS capable of files versioned per user

Tags: version-control

I have already used some VCS like CVS, SVN and Git. One feature that I am missing cannot be found anywhere.

There are files which I would like to have in the repository but every user should have its own. So when you checkout you get a default of that file and that commit your changes only for yourself.

Why do I want this? There are some files like configuration where I would like to have a default version in the repository (e.g. for building releases or a starting base for new team members) but the changes to that file are only relevant to a certain developer (or working copy) because it will contain paths only valid for that developer/working copy.

Currently when I do not add this files:
- I miss them when creating a new working copy or exporting for a release build
- Have no history which changes I might have done for myself for experimenting

Currently when I add this files to the repository:
- I might never commit them so I have a default in the repository but my file is always flagged "changed". In SVN I can add it to the "ignore-on-commit" changelist to improve a bit.
- I might loose my very own changes of a difficult configuration file (data crash, laptop theft, etc.)

Is there a VCS capable of this? Do SNV or git support something regarding this I might have overseen?

Comment: SVN - Branch per user + Pristine Branch. *Sapienti sat!*

Comment: This would mean a lot of sync with the trunk and more conflicts which have to be solved manually.

Comment: No. No merges at all (unless "templates" changed on the fly in the middle of cycle). Second try...

Comment: @LazyBadger: Please try to explain in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understood and decomposed** your task correctly

"Have a set of default templates of *something*, which are starting point of per-user customization and these customized versions must be stored separately and be accessible only by responsible person"

you can use this workflow (draft, subject of modifications and corrections), Subversion based for simplicity and transparent management (strong point of any CVCS really)

- Subversion repository
- Each user of repo have own predefined path inside repository-tree (with common path-pattern for manageability and easy automation of processes)
- One special admin-only managed path also exist, not accessible by ordinary users

Our tree may seems like this (where Repository dir is a root of repository)

```
z:\>dir /s /B
z:\Repository
z:\Repository\Users
z:\Repository\Template
z:\Repository\Users\Alpha
z:\Repository\Users\Bravo
```

- For every user-path we use Path-based Authentication, which provides access for every and each user only to own subtree in repository,
- Template contains (as name assumes) templates stub for all user's documents
- Adding new users to repo, obviously, becomes simple and easy automated task:

  - `svn copy` Template into new user's dir
  - add rw permissions for created location for user in authz-file
  - tell user URL of his personal tree in repo

Comment: So you check out the repository and only get the user-folder you have r/w access rights?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the VCS is the problem here. It looks like if you have a file whose contents are dependent on the local environment, you should auto-generate it with a script. This way, you ignore the generated file, but version the script and each developer still gets a perfectly valid copy of the config files at run time. This is the same approach that is used, for example, with user specific IDE settings: .suo files on Visual Studio for example.

Update:

If you specifically need a set of defaults, then the solution is this:

1. Add the defaults to the repository.
2. Each dev works in their own branch. This way, they can version the
   changes to the config files.
3. When re-basing onto master and/or merging, the devs simply never
   merge their customized configs.
4. You can always set up a hook to check if the default config has been modified, and if so, maybe email the dev. You simply view such a commit the same as you would view a commit that does not compile.

Devs are smart. Sure, they make mistakes. But never under-estimate the power of some simple communication.

Of course, when the default configs do get overwritten with the customized ones of Dev X, then you use the powers of git to fix that commit immediately.

Comment: That is a good approach to the paths but not other configuration settings which depend more on what part of your application you currently modify.

Comment: From your question, "...because it will contain paths only valid for that developer/working copy." you only mention paths. If you could update the question to explain things a little more (like for example, what method you use to determine the part of the application that is currently being modified), I could then fine tune my answer.

Comment: The configuration contains the path to different resources which might be different on each developer machine. Also there is a DB configuration which might lead to a DB with different master data which a developer might chose and also some application workflow settings.